# Is it possible to develop Hybrid mobile applications using Java + (Cordova/Titanium)

Tags: android, cordova, image-processing, titanium

I am hoping to develop a cross-platform image manipulation application  for Android and iOS. I  was thinking of using a development framework such as titanium mobile or Cordova but i was unable to find any image manipulation / processing library for them

I just want to know the possibility of developing the core image manipulation part using Java/ObjectiveC for the specific platforms and develop a common crossplatform front end using Titanium/Cordova
Is it possible to develop Hybrid Mobile applications using development frameworks such as titanium or cordova(phoneGap) while still having a part of code written in Java

Answer (score 2):

Yes. its possible. if you are going the PhoneGap route, you need to create a **PhoneGap plugin** for this: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

Once you create the plugin, you can invoke your native methods using Javascript.

Creating plugin for Android: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android
Creating Plugin for iOS: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Both PhoneGap and Titanium let you do this. The title of this question seems to imply you want to do JAVA development for iOS, which isn't possible (at least not with Titanium or PhoneGap).

Titanium has a development guide on how to extend the platform:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile

It links to articles particular to iOS and Android.